# Why is key_len greater than index length?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using innodb, I have an index on `(int,date)`.

When I run an explain on my query which uses the index, I see a `key_len` of 9.

That doesn't make sense to me. `int` takes 4 bytes. Date takes 3 bytes. That's 7 bytes of index length, why is `key_len` greater than that?

Comment: Can either be `NULL`?

Comment: yes. both can be NULL

Comment: @CAB: Right, well, where do you think that information is stored? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that both columns are nullable (e.g. `DEFAULT NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`). This was the tipoff for me to Google `mysql key_len nullable`, which eventually led me to [storage requirements in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html). On that page, Jake Drew posted a huge SQL statement that estimates the size of a row in a particular table. The part relevant to your question here is `CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. This means one byte is used to tell whether each nullable column holds `NULL` or an actual value.

So you have 4 bytes for one column, 3 bytes for a second column, 1 byte for whether the first column `IS NULL`, and 1 byte for whether the second column `IS NULL`. This gives a total of 9 bytes.

Comment: Reference update: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html "An SQL NULL value reserves one or two bytes in the record directory"